# Question concerning $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ versus $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that "Every $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$."

But isn't any $n$-dimensional vector space just $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well? Why don't they just say $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $V \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the representation.  $\mathbb{R}^n$ specifically refers to vectors with $n$ entries.  Vector spaces like $P_{n-1}$ (polynomials of degree at most $n-1$) are represented in a different way, but the vector spaces are isomorphic.

The statement is more general than $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ since $\mathbb{R}^n$ indicates a specific representation/type of data (and excludes other representations).  $\mathbb{R}^n$ doesn’t just indicate $n$-dimensional space, but a particular $n$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

The space of all polynomials with degree at most $n-1$ is an example of an $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$.  This space is not equal to $\mathbb R^{n}$ but it is isomorphic to it.

Answer (score 1):

I second Kava Rama Murthy's answer.  Notice that saying "all n dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic" **means** that we can rewrite a statement about a general vector space into a statement about R[sup]n[/sup] word for word.  Working about the vector $ax^3+ bx^2+ cx+ d$ I can simply use (a, b, c, d) instead.  Again, the two vector spaces are "isomorphic" but they are not the same vector space.

(And note that this isomorphism only applies to **finite** dimensional vector spaces.)